# ICollection.Add(item) don´t raise propertychanged MVVM datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid

My problem is this:
I use EF code first and I got a master detail situation, the master have a childs wich are the itemsSource for a datagrid, like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Transaction.StockItems,Mode=TwoWay}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=StockItem, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Width="0.12*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Width="0.12*" Binding="{Binding Cod}"/>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Width="0.12*" Binding="{Binding Cost}"/>
        <mui:DataGridTextColumn Width="0.15*" Binding="{Binding Qt}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my ViewModel I got a property for the `Transaction` property, like this:

```
    private tTran_t;
    public tTransaccion Transaction
    {
        get { return _t; }
        set { _t= value; RaisePropertyChanged("Transaction"); }
    }
```

In other method of my ViewModel I do an `Add()` to the collection, like this:

```
    Transaction.StockItems.Add(myNewLine);
    RaisePropertyChanged("Transaction");
```

In my Model the definition of `Transaction.StockItems` is `ICollection`.

**The problem:** the datagrid never got updated

I guess this is because the `RaisPropertyChanged()` is never called, because the collection is never set, but as you can see, I do call the `RaisPropertyChanged()` of the `Transaction` object.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your Transaction property should be an ObesrvableCollection<T> where T is the Model you want to show

Comment: the problem is the collection within the Transaction property is iCollection, and that was generated by EFcodeFirst 

         public virtual ICollection<stk> StockItem { get; set; }

should I change the type asigned by EFCodeFirst ?

Comment: No. From my knowledge, it's a bad habit to use The generated entiy from EF as you MVVM or MVP design pattern. You can use [DTO][1] or create your customized model from the EF model.

[1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx

Comment: It's not a bad habit. Having two sets of classes with the exact same properties that have to be translated back and forth is a huge waste of time. So is raising a property change notification for property A when you've added an item to property B.  `StockItems` should be a collection that implements INotifyCollectionChanged.  Looks like OP is just copypasting random code into his application.

Comment: @Will ,you are right.(bad habit is not the good word i want to use)i am used to do this separation to avoid the strong dependence. Business logic is separated to my chosen Client App design pattern. And when using this separation, i ll have only somework to do in my business logic when upgrdaing EF. My Client app wont be impacated. :)

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil Which brings us to why EF is a bad design choice :)

Comment: Well I don`t think thats bad, actually I really like to use EF codefirst,.. but anyway, the question is, what to do, to make use of the generated property **StockItems** in order to bind it in a datagrid? Should I use another property , an ObservableCollection property to bind the datagrid?and  move the objets from StockItems to myBindableStockItems, and myBindableStockItems to StockItems before Save the changes??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding an item to a collection doesn't "change" the object itself. a RaisepropertyChanged is raised when the collection itself is set. so what you need to do is assigning a new collection to your collection reference. So First you add item to a temporary collection then you do `transaction = new collection(temporaryCollection)` then your UI will ne notified of a change.